# Rewrite a variable type on the basis if condition in golang

Tags: go

I come from a python background and a newbie in Golang.
I started to write some code in Golang and came across an issue of setting a data type on the basis of if condition.
On working with the Govmomi module, I came across a [Retrieve](https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/blob/15d36b27b1375b9f85a86cb67902cb41645e168c/view/container_view.go#L39) method that accepts the last parameter as an interface.

In my script, I'm checking for an argument like the following

```
    var hss []mo.HostSystem
    var ds []mo.Datastore

    if command == "VMFS" {
        err = v.Retrieve(ctx, []string{commandChoices[command]}, []string{"name", "summary"}, &ds)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        for _, host := range ds {
            fmt.Println(host.Name)
        }
    } else {
        err = v.Retrieve(ctx, []string{commandChoices[command]}, []string{"name", "summary"}, &hss)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        for _, host := range hss {
            fmt.Println(host.Name)
    }
```

More of this code is boilerplate code that I wanted to avoid but not sure how to set a data type on the basis of an if condition. I'm looking for something like

```
if command == "VMFS" {
dss = []mo.Datasore
} else {
dss = []mo.HostSystem
}
```

And then pass dss as the last argument to *Retrieve* method.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Argument to Retrieve is an interface.https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/blob/15d36b27b1375b9f85a86cb67902cb41645e168c/view/container_view.go#L39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare variable `dss` with the type of the argument. Assign values to the variable as appropriate.

```
var dss interface{}
if command == "VMFS" {
    dss = &[]mo.Datastore{}
} else {
    dss = &[]mo.HostSystem{}
}
err = v.Retrieve(ctx, []string{commandChoices[command]}, []string{"name", "summary"}, dss)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: I get the error syntax error: unexpected &, expecting type

Comment: @Ashwin Are `HostSystem` and `Datastore` types in package `mo`?  Which line of code has the syntax error?

Comment: Maybe I used some stale code, it didn't complain now when I executed the code shared by you.
However, when I tried to range over the dss variable, I get the error : cannot range over dss (type interface {})

Comment: @Ashwin, that's expected.  If you need to execute different code based on the value of `command`, then the code in the question is the better approach.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks for giving me a direction.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an empty interface just like your method receives. You can also look at this example https://tour.golang.org/methods/14

In your specific case you want:

```
var dss interface{}
if command == "VMFS"{
  dss = []mo.Datasore
}else{
  dss = []mo.HostSystem
}
```

Comment: I get the following error :
./main.go:118:8: type []mo.Datastore is not an expression
./main.go:120:8: type []mo.HostSystem is not an expression

Answer (score 0):

A few changes over the answers by A_kat and Muffin.

You can do:

```
if command == "VMFS" {
  dss := []mo.Datasore{}
}else{
  dss := []mo.HostSystem{}
}

err = v.Retrieve(ctx, []string{commandChoices[command]}, []string{"name", "summary"}, &dss)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

This will not give you error when iterating over the range of `dss`